# DataProtector backup session stucks in "Inactive/Waiting" status

Tags: sql-server, backup, data-protector

DataProtector v. 11.01

Backup session stucks in "Inactive/Waiting" status. There are no requests detected on DB-server. On the other hand, other sessions (for another DB`s on the same DB-server) goes fine.

Tried to create back-up specification - no use.
Tried to reboot CM-server - no use.
Launch CM-server in debug-mode - I get lots of log-files, but nothing useful inside. No warnings, fail-messages or something else.

I'd welcome any help!